# Security in Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, thrift

How are Cassandra clusters usually built in security way? Should they always be kept locally or are there any security functions that makes it reasonable to open up for external connections to the cluster? As far as I've understand I seems like Cassandra doesn't have any "inbuild security engine" for handling these kind of things. I'm planning on building a service to talk with the Cassandra from, should that connection be made locally (on the same net as the cluster) or from external using the DNS?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra supports builtin password authentication and authorisation since version 1.2. 
User credentials and privileges are kept internally, in system auth tables. This can be viewed as its "inbuild security engine".

As for protecting connections (encryption), since version 1.2, there's SSL support for both internode and client-to-node communication. DataStax Enterprise platform additionally extends that with Kerberos/LDAP support to allow single-sign-on.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a stateful firewall to allow incoming connections, but allow outgoing only if someone requested something from the server. Also C* has inbuilt SSL support, but not all APIs can use the SSL, so you'll have to pick a compatible one.